# How to use Terraform to approve a Managed Private Endpoint on a Blob Storage ADLS Gen2?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-synapse, azure-rm

I have created several managed private endpoints on a Synapse Analytics workspace using Terraform.
Now I do not know how to "Approve" them since I cannot seem to find the right resource to perform this action.

To do it manually I need to go to the Storage account -> Networks -> Private Endpoints, selected the ones to be "Approved" and press Approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of today, you can't approve a Managed Private Endpoint using Terraform.

You may checkout the [Synapse Managed Private Endpoint - auto_approval option](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/synapse-managed-private-endpoint-auto-approval-option/25238) which has already asked in the hashicorp.

**Note:** `Azure PowerShell` and `Azure CLI` are the preferred methods for managing Private Endpoint connections on Microsoft Partner Services or customer owned services.

For more details, refer to [Manage Private Endpoint connections on a customer/partner owned Private Link service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/manage-private-endpoint#manage-private-endpoint-connections-on-a-customerpartner-owned-private-link-service).

Answer (score 4):

If you're still interested, I've done this in Terraform like so:

```
resource "null_resource" "endpoint_approval" {
  depends_on = [module.sql_managed_endpoint, module.storage_managed_endpoint]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<-EOT
          $sql_id = $(az network private-endpoint-connection list --id ${module.mssql_server.id} --query "[?contains(properties.privateEndpoint.id, 'vnet')].id" -o json) | ConvertFrom-Json
          $storage_id = $(az network private-endpoint-connection list --id ${module.storage_account.storage_account_id} --query "[?contains(properties.privateEndpoint.id, 'vnet')].id" -o json) | ConvertFrom-Json
          az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $sql_id --description "Approved in Terraform"
          az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $storage_id --description "Approved in Terraform"
        EOT
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @philthy. This worked for me. Personally, I just had to add a command to perform az login etc before it would list the available endpoints and then approve them.


`az login --service-principal -u ${data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id} -p ${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sp.value} --tenant ${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to approve the private endpoint connection with Terraform.
Please see the example below to approve a managed private endpoint between a Synapse Analytics workspace and a storage account.
The trick is to use the `azapi` provider to retrieve and filter the private endpoint connections on the storage account and then approve it.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplestorageacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = "true"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "example"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
  name                                 = "example"
  resource_group_name                  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id
  sql_administrator_login              = "sqladminuser"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  managed_virtual_network_enabled      = true

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule" "example" {
  name                 = "AllowAll"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.id
  start_ip_address     = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address       = "255.255.255.255"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example_connect" {
  name                     = "examplestorage2"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "BlobStorage"
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                 = "example-endpoint"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.id
  target_resource_id   = azurerm_storage_account.example_connect.id
  subresource_name     = "blob"

  depends_on = [azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule.example]
}

# Retrieve the storage account details, including the private endpoint connections
data "azapi_resource" "example_storage" {
  type                   = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01"
  resource_id            = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  response_export_values = ["properties.privateEndpointConnections"]
}

# Retrieve the private endpoint connection name from the storage account based on the private endpoint name
locals {
  private_endpoint_connection_name = element([
    for connection in jsondecode(data.azapi_resource.example_storage.output).properties.privateEndpointConnections
    : connection.name
    if endswith(connection.properties.privateEndpoint.id, azurerm_synapse_managed_private_endpoint.example.name)
  ], 0)
}

# Approve the private endpoint
resource "azapi_update_resource" "approval" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/privateEndpointConnections@2022-09-01"
  name      = local.private_endpoint_connection_name
  parent_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState = {
        description = "Approved via Terraform"
        status      = "Approved"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, and works as expected even with PLS created for the Cognitive Search solution - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/search_shared_private_link_service

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need an approval from a managed private link of Azure Data Explorer in Azure Event Hubs.

In my case I have 2 private links, one is autoapproved, the second is a managed private link, so I reference it in the array with the index number 1, depending on you case you can modify it:

```
data "azapi_resource_list" "private_endpoint_list" {
  type                   = "Microsoft.EventHub/Namespaces/PrivateEndpointConnections@2021-11-01"
  parent_id              = data.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.demo.id
  response_export_values = ["value"]
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "approval" {
  type      = "Microsoft.EventHub/Namespaces/PrivateEndpointConnections@2021-11-01"
  name      = jsondecode(data.azapi_resource_list.private_endpoint_list.output)["value"][1].name
  parent_id = data.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.demo.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState = {
        description = "Approved via Terraform"
        status      = "Approved"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update, with this I made it also working in the delete process:

```
#auto aprobar el managed endpoint
data "azapi_resource_list" "private_endpoint_list" {
  type                   = "Microsoft.EventHub/Namespaces/PrivateEndpointConnections@2021-11-01"
  parent_id              = data.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.adh_ns.id
  response_export_values = ["value"]
  depends_on             = [azurerm_kusto_cluster_managed_private_endpoint.adh_managed_endpoint]
}

locals {
  parsed_json = jsondecode(data.azapi_resource_list.private_endpoint_list.output)
  pending_items = [for item in local.parsed_json.value : item.properties.privateLinkServiceConnectionState.status == "Pending" ? item : null]
  compacted_pending_items = [for item in local.pending_items : item if item != null]
}

resource "azapi_update_resource" "approval" {
  type      = "Microsoft.EventHub/Namespaces/PrivateEndpointConnections@2021-11-01"
  name      = try(local.compacted_pending_items[0].name, "dummy")
  parent_id = data.azurerm_eventhub_namespace.adh_ns.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      privateLinkServiceConnectionState = {
        description = "Approved via Terraform"
        status      = "Approved"
      }
    }
  })
  depends_on = [data.azapi_resource_list.private_endpoint_list]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [name]
  }
}
```